# Problem in CesiumJS left double click camera

Tags: javascript, typescript, cesiumjs

everybody! I’m adding to Entity Wall and Polyline. I also specify Model in the properties of the Entity. I have checkboxes that enable and disable Wall and Polyline. When they are enabled, when you double-click on an Entity, the camera points to the center of the Wall or Polyline. I need the camera to capture the Entity when double clicking on the Entity. What could be the reason?

I tried to find some property, but there is no such thing. Has anyone encountered this problem?

Set Postion Code:

```
const hpr = new HeadingPitchRoll(Math.toRadians(item.Q + 270), 0, 0);
  
      
      let position = Cartesian3.fromDegrees(
        item!.L * Math.DEGREES_PER_RADIAN,
        item!.B * Math.DEGREES_PER_RADIAN,
        item!.H                                  
      ) as Cartesian3;
    
      
      let orientation = Transforms.headingPitchRollQuaternion(
        position as Cartesian3,
        hpr
      ) as unknown as Ellipsoid;
```

Create Entity Code:

```
let entity = new Entity({
          id: item.UID,
          position: Cartesian3.fromDegrees(
            item!.L * Math.DEGREES_PER_RADIAN,
            item!.B * Math.DEGREES_PER_RADIAN,
            item!.H
          ) as Cartesian3,
          orientation: new CallbackProperty(() => {
            return orientation;
          }, false),
          model: model,
          objectType: objectType,
        });
```

Create Wall Code:

```
let wall = new WallGraphics({
            material: MColor(item.color, 0.1),
            outline: true,
            outlineColor: Color.GREY,
            show: false,
            positions: new CallbackProperty(() => {
              let points
              if (objectType === EntitiesTypes.Air) {
                points = WallData!.get(item!.UID)
              }
              return Cartesian3.fromDegreesArrayHeights(points);
            }, false),
          });
    entity.wall = wall;
```

I was looking for a property of Entity, Wall and edit this.